# What bonus quest objectives are there, and what are the rewards?

Tags: diablo-iii

During one of the earliest quests in the game, [The Fallen Star](http://d3db.com/quest/i/the-fallen-star/27), you're given the objective to kill the Wretched Queen north of New Tristram.  At the same time, you're given the "Bonus" objective of killing three Wretched Mothers.

I'm doing my second playthrough of the game, in Nightmare mode now, and it occurred to me that since I've already been everywhere and seen everything, I might not want to complete all of the quest bonus objectives, but I have no idea what they are, or what the rewards are.

Does anyone know what bonus quest objectives exist, and what the rewards are?  Knowing this would help me streamline my second playthrough without missing any important rewards.

Comment: Bonus objectives are quite a letdown. There are so few of them, and they all require actions that the player would typically perform.

Answer (score 1):

I believe all of the bonus quests just give experience and gold.  I flipped through the official strategy guide and saw nothing to the contrary.  As for knowing which quests are bonus quests...they are labeled as such when you get them.